# Error al hacer insert, no puede convertir a string

Tags: php

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es, 2 `select` para recoger 2 valores y comprobarlos en la base de datos antes del `insert` y luego hacer el `insert`, pero cuando lo hago me salta este error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\beep\registrar.php on line 13

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';

$codigo_beep = $_POST["codigo_beep"];


    $sql1 = "SELECT empleados.id FROM empleados, codigos WHERE empleados.codigo LIKE codigos.id AND codigos.codigo = $codigo_beep;";
    $sql2 = "SELECT empleados.codigo FROM empleados, codigos WHERE empleados.codigo LIKE codigos.id AND codigos.codigo = $codigo_beep;";

    $resultado1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO registros (empleado,codigo,fecha,hora) VALUES ('$resultado1', '$resultado2', CURDATE(),CURTIME())";

    $resultado3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
    //$resultado3 = $mysqli->query($sql3);

header("Location:index.html");

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada podrías optimizar el código, ya que estás haciendo 2 consultas para devolver 2 campos de la misma tabla y la misma condición. Podrías hacer una única consulta que haga el insert con los registros del select que intentas hacer.

`mysqli_query` devuelve un **objeto** o devuelve FALSE en caso que la sentencia no haya ido bien. Sea como fuere, no devuelve un **string**.

Prueba este código a ver que tal. He eliminado las 2 consultas select y he juntado el insert into con el select para que inserte los registros que encuentre en el select.

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO registros (empleado,codigo,fecha,hora) SELECT empleados.id, empleados.codigo, CURDATE(), CURTIME() FROM empleados, codigos WHERE empleados.codigo LIKE codigos.id AND codigos.codigo = ".$_POST["codigo_beep"].";";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location:index.html");
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene el uso de `fetch_fields()` aquí? Por otra parte, el `INSERT` se puede hacer en base al `SELECT` sin necesidad de lanzar el `SELECT` por una parte y el `INSERT` por otra.

Comment: Correcto, sé que se puede hacer todo en una misma sentencia, pero si lo he hecho así es para mantener la estructura que daba. Ahora, si lo quieres todo en una misma sentencia, lo edito y lo pongo, no me supone ningún problema...

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que me has puesto es correcto, en el sentido de que no me da el error de string y tu explicación me ha quedado clara de lo que estaba fallando. Ahora es, no da error pero no me inserta nada en la bd

Comment: @amr07 por eso preguntaba cuál es el sentido de usar `fetch_fields` aquí. Si lo que quieres es insertar los datos obtenidos en el `SELECT` se debe cambiar `fetch_fields` por un método `fetch` que traiga los datos, no los campos. Y, si se necesita insertar todas las filas que traiga el `SELECT` hay que cambiar la forma de lectura (el `foreach` así como está no servirá). Ya que Ferran ha escrito la respuesta, sugiero que la modifique en ese sentido para poder insertar los datos que se extraen del   `SELECT`. Si hay algún problema y puedo ayudar, lo haré con gusto.

Comment: Entendido, pues voy a ver que puedo hacer

Comment: Editado, prueba a ver que tal...

Comment: @FerranMuñoz FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE!! No se como agradeceros la ayuda que me habéis prestado. Sabía la posibilidad de hacer dentro del insert las select y demás pero tiré por otro lado donde pensaba que lo podía hacer. Esto me ha servido para aprender, muchísimas gracias

Comment: @A.Cedano  FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE!! No se como agradeceros la ayuda que me habéis prestado. Sabía la posibilidad de hacer dentro del insert las select y demás pero tiré por otro lado donde pensaba que lo podía hacer. Esto me ha servido para aprender, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Me alegro @amr07, de todos modos, y perdonen Uds. que dé tanto la lata. La consulta es insegura y muy peligrosa. Un hacker podría manipular los datos de `$_POST["codigo_beep"]` e inyectar código malicioso en tu base de datos o en tu sistema. Ese código puede ir desde borrar todos tus datos, hasta extraer información sensible, obtener accesos, modificar archivos, y meterse hasta en la televisión de tu casa o teléfono de la empresa... así de simple. Entonces, **nunca pases variables en las consultas, pero nunca significa nunca**. Para prevenir eso, hay que usar **consultas preparadas**.

Comment: Va a ser un programa en local, pero a que te refieres con consultas preparadas?

Comment: @amr07, si te funcionó la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Buenos días @amr07, como dice Triby, si te ha servido la respuesta, marcala como aceptada :)